# Integrating Zxing library 2.2 in ios

Tags: ios, zxing

I downloaded Zxing library 2.2 and tried to integrate it for 1d/2d barcode scanning within my ios project. Multitudes of errors came in, the latest being NSORuntime errors ( I am pretty much sure it is because of the cpp files) ...... I tried to solve them, but they just keep appearing. I am at sea as to how integrate this barcode library into my ios project. Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered to same problems, so I decided to use sample project in the ZXing Sample. I removed xib files and added storyboards, also fixed some minor issues and voilà! Now its working flawless.